# Does the success of a website depend not only on the number of visits but on the target population too?

Tags: freelance-websites, marketing, business-plan, advertising

I think of building a website (may be with an android app too) that has games for kids (to train the brain, memory, attention ...etc). In case all goes well, how would the economic model be? I don't want to make it paid and I don't think the number of views count in the case of a website which most or all of its visitors are children because of two reasons :

- They don't have purchasing power for the ads displayed
- Their decision is easily compromised by their parents

So most advertisers would be rightfully reluctant to advertise on such a website. The proof: the web lacks famous websites that target this category versus [more visited are website targeting an older population](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most_popular_websites).

### The questions:

- Those are just my thoughts, please help me with your feedback and points that I'm missing.
- The objective is how could such websites be economically viable (websites which can generate a lot of visits, but within a population that is economically inactive)?

Many thanks,

Comment: I'd rather spend $10 to buy a high-quality ads-free app that is somehow useful to my kids' education, than use free apps full of spam, uncontrolled ads and brainwashing marketing. You should look at develop an high quality product that parents are happy to pay the right price.

Comment: You should probably edit the answer to remove invitation for opinionated answers. "Thoughts and feedback" is offtopic here.

Comment: Kids do not only have a lot of purchasing-power these days, the may also be view as influences (of their parents) and have been the targets of advertisements for a long time. You know the saying *get them while their young*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parents see value in their kids education and if it's fun for the kids they will want to play/use your websote/app - so it's a win-win. You may want to target the parents in your ad campaign or social media marketing with the benefits they can give their kids, and then target the kids with the fun aspects of your website/app.

In terms of payment strategy, you could work it like other SaaS companies and do a monthly subscription service as well as over a fixed term(3, 6 or 12 month) deal that gives them a discount.

Adding stats and badges on your program would help out a lot too. Gives the kids/users incentive to keep playing and get more rewards. (I.e. kids answer math questions or solve puzzles and gain points based on the number of correct answers/accuracy. Then they can use their points to pimp their avatar or get items that give them bonus skills.)

So you could use ads on free memberships for money if no one signs up, and paid get ad free experience plus better rewards, points or upgrades. (More detailed stats or advice on how to improve).

Hope this helps you out.

Best,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

I cant help you with your general economics (If I could, I would just do that business myself, wouldn´t I?)

What I can tell you is: Highly targeted Advertisement is normally payed way better than the broad "shower" approach.  Also, there are enough companies specifically targeting children. Children do have a lot of buying power nowadays. The can also be seen as influences and as young adults of tomorrow.